# Writing a line without using casting

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to understand something basic. Line 1:

```
[((ClassA *)self.tabBarController) MethodA:YES];
```

It does what it suppose to but I'm trying to write it in another way without success.
First, is the classA casting here? (just want to make sure)
Second, why doesn't this work:

```
ClassA *test=[[ClassA alloc]init];
[test.tabBarController MethodA:YES];
```

How can I write it so it would work without casting.
Thanks

Comment: Well, they're two different things.  You're like a kid on Christmas morning playing with the box and ignoring the toy inside.

Comment: And the only way to write it without casting is to change the definition of your current class so that tabBarController is declared as a ClassA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
[((ClassA *)self.tabBarController) MethodA:YES];
```

You are calling MethodA of ClassA

like (ClassA->MethodA:YES)
while In

```
ClassA *test=[[ClassA alloc]init];
[test.tabBarController MethodA:YES];
```

you r trying to call method MethodA of tabBarController which is in ClassA(test).

like(ClassA->tabBarController->MethodA)

and of corse MethodA is in ClassA not in tabBarController so it is not working

Comment: In other words, the first example typecasts the tabBarController towards ClassA. The second example does not.

Comment: So there isn't any other way doing so without casting?

Comment: He said: "It does what it suppose to but I'm trying to write it in another way without success. ".
The manual downcasting was working.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I don't understand you.

Comment: In few words, when you was doing: [((ClassA *)self.tabBarController) MethodA:YES]; This was working without any crash, wasn't it?